# Alternative method for solving $|3x-9|+|7x-8|-||20x-13|-3x|-3=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Recently I came across the following equation:
$$|3x-9|+|7x-8|-||20x-13|-3x|-3=0.$$

An obvious approach would be to divide it into cases and solve for each interval for each mod involved.
Another approach that came to my mind was to solve it graphically, however that was equally as laborious if not more.
It would be great help if anyone can suggest any other innovative method to help me solve this equation.

Comment: Is it written correctly?

Comment: if you divide x by the greatest common divisor of all your constants, the solution has to be an integer.

Comment: The outermost application of the absolute value is useless, you can remove that. Also, where did you come across it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this method:

To avoid the branching cases hell, you can go algebraic, i.e replace $|7x-8|=s\ (7x-8)$ with $s\in\{-1,+1\}$.

You do that for every absolute value encountered (that should give $4$) and lead to $f(s_1,s_2,\cdots)\ x+g(s_1,s_2,\cdots)=0$

Which is straightforward to solve.

This gives you $2^4$ candidate solutions (by pluging $\pm 1$ for each $s_i$), but this method introduces many spurious solutions (in fact the $s_i$ are not independent) so you have to test every candidate solution against the original equation.

Though since everything leads to rather simple calculations, this can be done quickly (preferably automated if you can with computer) and you are sure not to miss any solution.

---

Here is the detailed solve, please try to do it for yourself first

> $\begin{align}|3x-9|&+|7x-8|-||20x-13|-3x|-3\\&=(3x-9)s_1+(7x-8)s_2-((20x-13)s_3-3x)s_4-3\\&=(3s_1+7s_2-20s_3s_4+3s_4)x+(-9s_1-8s_2+13s_3s_4-3)\end{align}$

> $$x=\frac{9s_1+8s_2-13s_3s_4+3}{3s_1+7s_2-20s_3s_4+3s_4}$$

> Candidates $\frac{9}{11}, -\frac{1}{13}, -\frac{1}{7}, 1, \frac{11}{19}, \frac{5}{9}, \frac{5}{7}, \frac{11}{13}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{17}{19}, \frac{17}{13}, \frac{3}{7}, -\frac{7}{13}, 1, \frac{11}{9}, -1$

> Among which the real solutions are $1$ and $-\frac {1}{13}$

Comment: Just a little refinement I've just thought about since $3>\frac 87>\frac {13}{20}$ then $s_1\ge s_2\ge s_3$, and only $8$ candidates to examine instead of $16$.